# How can I shut down the PC after specified amount of time?

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

How would you go about turning you computer after a specified amount of time?

I listen music before I go to sleep and would like to be able to shutdown my computer after a specified amount of time. After ½ an hour say.

It would be cool if you could connect a desktop shortcut to a task in scheduler so you click the shortcut and ½ an hour later it shuts down.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [original recommendation - TimeComX](https://superuser.com/revisions/215533/3), is now only found on shared hosting sites and has been discontinued.

Via [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5577621/switch-off-shuts-down-your-computer-from-anywhere), this seems to be a worthy alternative (no personal experience):

> [Switch Off by AiryTec](http://www.airytec.com/en/switch-off/)

Several features of note:

- Schedule shutdowns by CPU usage levels, time, or remotely
- Power saving calculator
- Portable use (no install required - some note this version may not work on x64)

[image]
(image via developer)

Answer (score 121):

[Create a batch file](http://www.wikihow.com/Write-a-Batch-File), and put this code in it after the `@echo off` line:

```
shutdown -s -t 1800
```

The computer will shutdown 30 minutes (1800 seconds) after running the batch file.

To cancel a shutdown initiated by that batch file, you can go to **Start** → **Run** and type:

```
shutdown -a
```

Or put that in its own separate batch file, then run it to cancel a shutdown.

Answer (score 45):

[Here](http://g.123.tn/how-to-shutdown-automatically-my-pc) are simple steps to shutdown your computer after a specified time without any application!:

1. Open the Run window (Windows Key+R) or (Start / All Programs / Accessories / Run).
2. Key `shutdown -s -t 1800`:

[image: SU215531 example]

[`1800`(can be changed) is the number of seconds after which the computer will turn off.]

3. Click on <kbd>OK</kbd> and your computer will turn off after the specified time (here 30 minutes).

You can change `-s` for alternatives as below:

```
options    effect
-l         to log off
-r         to reboot
```

Answer (score 5):

Go to **Control Panel** → **Power Options** → **Change Plan Settings** and change the **Put the computer to sleep after** option to whatever you want.

Comment: That is a bit long winded.can you think of something that is more automatic. Like a simple click of a desktop icon an my computer shuts down in 1/2 an hour.

Comment: and that only puts the computer to sleep. I want to shut down the computer.

Comment: Well that setting is automatic -- once you set it one time, say to one hour, the system will then automatically go to sleep within an hour of your computer going idle (you don't have to run through the steps again). But yes, that will only let you put the PC to sleep. To shut it down, you would need to use a different program (like the one suggested below).

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: This application has been discontinued, please use an alternative.

{{ Link Removed }} can do this for you, the free version meets your requirements.

[image]

Comment: Dont click the link. The site must have been hacked. Link redirects to some spam sites.

Comment: @sudip I've amended my answer to remove the link.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with task scheudler and a bat file

Create a bat file by: open notepad, and type the string

`shutdown.exe /s /t 00`

Save this file to your My Documents directory and name it Shutdown.bat (note the `.bat` extension and not `.txt`).

Then, open Task Scheulder (type `task s` from start menu)

Create a new task (not basic)

Give it a name

On idle

In Conditions tab, select `start the task only if the computer is idle for 30 minutes`

Now, in Actions tab, click New start a program and brose for your .bat file.

Click OK until it's saved!

All done!

As an aside, just be careful in regards that you may lose unsaved work; Also, this *may* not be desirable if a background update is running or a download etc

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple VBScript that will shutdown Windows at a specified time

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 

Dim Input
Input = "10:00"

'Input = InputBox("Enter the shutdown time here.","", "10:00") 

For i = 1 to 2

CurrentTime = Time & VbCrLf

If Left(CurrentTime,5) = Input Then

objShell.Run "shutdown -s -t 00", 0
WScript.Quit 1

Else

WScript.Sleep 1000

End If

i=i-1

Next
```

Comment: This would only loop twice.....

Answer (score -3):

open start -> write `cmd` and open it.

Then write

```
shutdown /t -s 600
```

(for, e.g., 600 seconds)

Comment: You'll have to add this to startup, but other than that this is probably the best way.

Comment: I don't see where this adds more info to the existing answers from Force Flow's or Dave Rook. It's always the same mechanic behind.

Comment: Think you meant shutdown -s -t 600 here. Yours won't execute in its current syntax.