# How can I make windows 8 shutdown automaticaly after a set amount of time?

Tags: windows, shutdown

Is there a way to set a timer that will automatically switch my laptop off after a given amount of time?

I like listening to music before bed and at the moment I need to get up to turn the laptop off.

Comment: Here you go: http://superuser.com/questions/215531/how-can-i-shut-down-the-pc-after-specified-amount-of-time

Answer (score 1):

**2 ways to set up Windows 8/8.1 auto shutdown:**

---

**Way 1: Set up Windows 8/8.1 auto shutdown through run command.**

**Step 1:** Open Run dialog box.

Press Windows key+X to open the Quick Access Menu, and choose Run in it. BTW, you can also press Windows key and R key at the same time to directly open Run dialog box.

**Step 2:** Enter a shutdown command in the empty box.

The command inputted is a little dissimilar according to different time you want to set up to automatically shut down your computer. For more info, please refer to the following example.

If you want to make the computer automatically turn off in 30 minutes, you can type "shutdown –s –t 1800" or "shutdown.exe –s –t 1800" (without double quotation marks) in the box and click OK.

**Tips:** The number, 1800, in the command stands for 1800 seconds. That is to say, the computer will turn off after 1800 seconds (30 minutes). Moreover, you can decide the time to make the computer automatically shut down by changing the number in the form of seconds in this command.

Then, the system will prompt you that you're about to be signed off.

---

**Way 2: Set up Windows 8/8.1 auto shutdown through Task Scheduler.**

**Step 1:** Right-click Computer and select Manage in the menu to open Computer Management.

**Step 2:** Click Task Scheduler on the left list to open it, and choose Create Basic Task on the right side.

**Step 3:** Input shutdown as the basic task name and tap Next to move on.

**Step 4:** In Trigger, choose when do you want the task to start from Daily, Weekly, Monthly, One time, When the computer starts, When I log on and When a specific event is logged. After that, click Next.

**Step 5:** Set the start date, shutdown time and frequency. Then, tap Next to continue.

**Step 6:** In Action, make sure Start a program is selected and click Next.

**Step 7:** In Start a Program, enter C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe as the program/script name, input -s as argument and tap Next.

**Step 8:** In the next interface, click Finish to complete the settings.

Source: http://www.isunshare.com/windows-8/windows-8-8.1-auto-shutdown-how-to-set-up.html

Answer (score 0):

the `shutdown.exe` command, built into Windows, will do the trick.  Here is an [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491003.aspx) explaining how to use it.

Or type the following for an interactive GUI:

`shutdown /i`

Answer (score 0):

I know how to do that in Windows 7 but I guess that is almost the same process like in Windows 8. Basically all what you need to do is to enter in Control Panel / System and Security / Administrative Tools and then click on Task Scheduler where you can menage all the things not only for shutdown but also and for other actions. Here you can see how it works step by step just follow text in this [blog](http://pc-problem-solutions.blogspot.com/2014/02/set-automatic-shutdown-on-your-pc.html) :